# GeometryReader Takes Extra Space in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, button, swiftui, geometryreader

The code below is to create a custom button

```
import SwiftUI

let skyBlue = Color(red: 75/255, green: 170/255, blue: 193/255)

struct RegisterButtonView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            HStack {
                Spacer()

                Text("Register")
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.white))
                    .font(.system(size: geo.size.width / 20))
                    .bold()

                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(width: geo.size.width * 4/9, height: geo.size.height / 7)
            .background(skyBlue)
            .cornerRadius(60)
        }

    }
}

struct RegisterButtonView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RegisterButtonView()
    }
}
```

However, the whole button view contains the extra space introduced by the GeometryReader, so that when I put this view to a root view, the space cannot be eliminated.

[image: Image for Preview]

Comment: Welcome on board. It is not extra space - `GeometryReader` does consume **all** available space. That's a feature.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible that I can make my RegisterButtonView only contain its shape without the white space? (In case I have to use GeometryReader)

Comment: The problem is that the size of the `RegisterButtonView` is based on the size of the `Text`, and the size of the `Text` is based on its font size, and the font size is based on the size of the `GeometryReader`. `GeometryReader` takes all the size given to it by its parent. In this case, the parent is the root view. So tell us what you want the size of the `RegisterButtonView` to be based on, if not on the size of the `GeometryReader`?

Comment: I actually want its size to be based on the shape of the button, which I think is the `HStack`.

Comment: It's clear that Apple uses magic (not SwiftUI) when implementing Button and other stuff. So they can do stuff like detecting when a touchUpInsideButton happens but we can't

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set the frame of GeoReader directly.

```
    struct RegisterButtonView: View {
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        HStack {
            Spacer()

            Text("Register")
                .foregroundColor(Color(.white))
                .font(.system(size: geo.size.width / 20 * 9 / 4))
                .bold()

            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(width: geo.size.width , height: geo.size.height )
        .background(skyBlue)
        .cornerRadius(60)
    }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 4/9 , height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 7)

}
}
```

Comment: But setting the GeoReader would actually stretch the whole view instead of just chopping off the blank.